# Integrating if inside ms sql query

Tags: sql-server

I need to run a query dependent on the value of a field read by that specific query.
This is my query :

```
SELECT * FROM foo JOIN bar ON bar.ID = foo.field1
```

if `foo.field1` is `0`, the `JOIN` is to be made on `foo.field2`

I've tried something like

```
SELECT * FRMO foo JOIN bar ON bar.ID = (SELECT field1 FROM bar WHERE field1 != 0)
```

but I'm not sure how how to write the next part, for when `field1` is actually `0`.

Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
JOIN bar 
    ON bar.ID = CASE foo.field1 WHEN 0 THEN foo.field2 ELSE foo.field1 END
```